# Python regex disallowed characters still accepted?

Tags: python, regex

```
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!£&*@#-_=+"
b = 0
username = input("Enter a username: ")
while b == 0:
    if len(username) < 6 or len(username) > 16:
        print("Incorrect length, try again.")
        break
    else:
        valid = re.search(a, username)
        if valid:
            print("Invalid characters entered, try again")
            break
        else:
            print("Username accepted")
            break
```

This is my code to check whether a user-entered username fits into certain parameters, but it doesn't properly work. The issue is that, when I run it, characters that are entered but aren't in the allowed list are still accepted.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I think you should check if the number of groups that do not match your regex in the string are equal to 1 or not. If not, then there are invalid characters.
Use this to guide yourself to update the regex: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four mistakes here:

1. you swapped `valid` and `not valid`: so you write to the screen that the username is invalid in case `re.search(..)` succeeds;
2. you do not ask the user to enter a new username;
3. you break even in case the string has invalid characters;
4. your regex looks for a *sequence* `'abcd...'` (so an `'a'` followed by a `'b'`, etc.).

The first three items can be solved easily by using `not` and placing the query inside the loop:

```
while b == 0:
    username = input("Enter a username: ")
    if len(username) < 6 or len(username) > 16:
        print("Incorrect length, try again.")
    else:
        if not re.search(a, username):
            print("Invalid characters entered, try again")
        else:
            print("Username accepted")
            break
```

For the second ony you need to alter your regex. First of all by specifying a *word group*:

```
[a-z0-9A-Z!£&*@#_=+-]
```

which we repeat zero or more times:

```
[a-z0-9A-Z!£&*@#_=+-]*
```

and with start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors:

```
^[a-z0-9A-Z!£&*@#_=+-]*$
```

So we can write it as:

```
a = '^[a-z0-9A-Z!£&*@#_=+-]*$'
b = 0
while b == 0:
    username = input("Enter a username: ")
    if len(username) < 6 or len(username) > 16:
        print("Incorrect length, try again.")
    else:
        if not re.search(a, username):
            print("Invalid characters entered, try again")
        else:
            print("Username accepted")
            break
```

But still the code is very inelegant:

1. You use a variable `b` to construct a loop, but `True` is more clear;
2. you can use operator chaining to check the length of the username.

So an improved code fragment could look like:

```
a = '^[a-z0-9A-Z!£&*@#_=+-]*$'

while True:
    username = input("Enter a username: ")
    if not 6 <= len(username) <= 16:
        print("Incorrect length, try again.")
    elif not re.search(a, username):
        print("Invalid characters entered, try again")
    else:
        print("Username accepted")
        break
```

**Example session:**

```
Enter a username: f
Incorrect length, try again.
Enter a username: blablablablablablablabla
Incorrect length, try again.
Enter a username: foobar<>~~
Invalid characters entered, try again
Enter a username: fooba
Incorrect length, try again.
Enter a username: foobar
Username accepted
```